Full Text Search on Postgres jsonb column
So I have an alert table like this:
my_db=> \d alerts_alert
                                     Table "public.alerts_alert"
     Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |             Default
----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 received_at    | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 id             | bigint                   |           | not null | generated by default as identity
 data           | jsonb                    |           | not null |
 updated_at     | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 status         | character varying(8)     |           | not null |
 owner_id       | uuid                     |           |          |
 resolved_by_id | uuid                     |           |          |
Indexes:
    "alerts_alert_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "alerts_aler_data_eae7f5_gin" gin (data)
    "alerts_alert_data_gin" gin (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(data::text, ''::text)))
    "alerts_alert_owner_id_0c00548a" btree (owner_id)
    "alerts_alert_resolved_by_id_b59cbeaf" btree (resolved_by_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "alerts_alert_owner_id_0c00548a_fk_accounts_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES accounts_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "alerts_alert_resolved_by_id_b59cbeaf_fk_accounts_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (resolved_by_id) REFERENCES accounts_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED

I do want to perform a full text search on the data column.
I have came up with this query but it performs poorly:
my_db=> explain analyze WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, received_at, data, updated_at, owner_id, resolved_by_id, status,
         to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(data::text, '')) AS search_vector
  FROM alerts_alert
)
SELECT id, received_at, data, updated_at, owner_id, resolved_by_id, status, search_vector,
       ts_rank(search_vector, websearch_to_tsquery('english'::regconfig, 'haykd')) AS rank
FROM cte
WHERE search_vector @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english'::regconfig, 'haykd')
ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 21;

Here is what it gives me:
                                                                        QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1518.59..1529.61 rows=21 width=194) (actual time=3891.969..3952.546 rows=21 loops=1)
   ->  Result  (cost=1518.59..2195.31 rows=1289 width=194) (actual time=3891.962..3952.522 rows=21 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=1518.59..1521.81 rows=1289 width=162) (actual time=3868.134..3868.145 rows=21 loops=1)
               Sort Key: (ts_rank(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE((alerts_alert.data)::text, ''::text)), '''haykd'''::tsquery)) DESC
               Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 28kB
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on alerts_alert  (cost=538.11..1483.83 rows=1289 width=162) (actual time=19.143..3862.893 rows=1327 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE((data)::text, ''::text)) @@ '''haykd'''::tsquery)
                     Heap Blocks: exact=202
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on alerts_alert_data_gin  (cost=0.00..537.79 rows=1289 width=0) (actual time=12.832..12.832 rows=1432 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE((data)::text, ''::text)) @@ '''haykd'''::tsquery)
 Planning Time: 35.525 ms
 Execution Time: 3953.748 ms

The table is not big, it has only 12k rows in it.
Any recommendations how to make this faster? I'm on PostgreSQL 16
Update:
As recommended in the comments running explain (analyze, buffers) after setting track_io_timing = on:  here is what I have got:
my_db=> explain (analyze, buffers) WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, received_at, data, updated_at, owner_id, resolved_by_id, status,
         to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(data::text, '')) AS search_vector
  FROM alerts_alert
)
SELECT id, received_at, data, updated_at, owner_id, resolved_by_id, status, search_vector,
       ts_rank(search_vector, websearch_to_tsquery('english'::regconfig, 'haykd')) AS rank
FROM cte
WHERE search_vector @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english'::regconfig, 'haykd')
ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 21;
                                                                       QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=3064.58..3075.61 rows=21 width=194) (actual time=3029.762..3089.928 rows=21 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=5518
   ->  Result  (cost=3064.58..3766.51 rows=1337 width=194) (actual time=3029.761..3089.919 rows=21 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=5518
         ->  Sort  (cost=3064.58..3067.93 rows=1337 width=162) (actual time=3007.831..3007.840 rows=21 loops=1)
               Sort Key: (ts_rank(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE((alerts_alert.data)::text, ''::text)), '''haykd'''::tsquery)) DESC
               Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 28kB
               Buffers: shared hit=5417
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on alerts_alert  (cost=2055.61..3028.54 rows=1337 width=162) (actual time=4.503..3005.258 rows=1337 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE((data)::text, ''::text)) @@ '''haykd'''::tsquery)
                     Heap Blocks: exact=204
                     Buffers: shared hit=5414
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on alerts_alert_data_gin  (cost=0.00..2055.28 rows=1337 width=0) (actual time=2.097..2.097 rows=1465 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE((data)::text, ''::text)) @@ '''haykd'''::tsquery)
                           Buffers: shared hit=482
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=276 read=2
   I/O Timings: shared/local read=1.171
 Planning Time: 35.782 ms
 Execution Time: 3090.356 ms

I'm running on AWS RDS on db.t4g.micro

It looks like you have very slow IO.  You could verify it by turning track_io_timing on and then running EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS).  (or just be repeating the query back and back and seeing if the 2nd run is faster).  You could try to speed it up by increasing effective_io_concurrency, but how effective that is will depend on your IO system.

Yes, we need EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), ideally after setting track_io_timing = on.

The whole point of JSON is that it is /structured/ data - /where/ a datum appears within the structure /matters/.  Full-Text Searching is for /unstructured/ data - /where/ a datum appears doesn't matter.
I can't help feeling that you're mixing apples and oranges here and, quite likely, getting guacamole!

I have run it and updated the original question. Please take a look (under Update section). Thanks!

@PhillW.  if I have semi-structured/unstructured data, what type of field would you recommend for storing it? This data originates from various third-party tools and can consist of any key/value pairs including nested arrays and objects. I need to enable full-text search on it.

Let the people who asked for it that you've now run EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,...) <your query>.

The full text index:
"alerts_alert_data_gin" gin (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(data::text, ''::text)))

is used for the Bitmap index scan, but any time the engine needs the tsvector for anything else in the query, data::text will go again through the full text parser. This part is CPU-intensive and can really undermine the search performance, unless the text contents are tiny.
In particular the ts_rank() call causes the execution of to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(data::text, ''))  for all 1337 matching rows in your example.
This could be avoided by materializing this expression as a column in the table (and of course creating the GIN index on this column).

That worked, I have added it as a column and added the index on it. Thanks!
